# Постановка тире

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте. Много раз видел постановку тире перед возрастом.
Например:

Мне 40, брату - 37.

Правильно ли это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно,и не только перед возрастом,это интонационное тире в неполном предложении для логического подчёркивания :
http://www.xliby.ru/jazykoznanie/spravochnik_po_russkomu_jazyku_punktuacija/p2.php

Answer (score 0):

> Мне 40, брату - 37.

А почему тогда после "мне" нет тире?